# Remove substring from array of python strings

Tags: python, string

I have an array of strings that I am scraping that looks like this `["https://rotogrinders.com/players/charlie-culberson-13456?format=json",
"https://rotogrinders.com/players/charlie-culberson-13456?format=json"]`

I want to remove the `https://rotogrinders.com/players/` part from each string in the array. How would I do this?

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By 
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait 
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC 
from selenium.common.exceptions import TimeoutException

browser = webdriver.Chrome("/ProgramData/chocolatey/bin/chromedriver.exe") 

browser.get("https://rotogrinders.com/projected-stats/mlb-hitter?site=fanduel")

# Wait 20 seconds for page to load
timeout = 20
try:
    WebDriverWait(browser, timeout).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CLASS_NAME, 'player-popup')))
except TimeoutException:
    print("Timed out waiting for page to load")
    browser.quit()

# find_elements_by_xpath returns an array of selenium objects.

players_info = []

players = browser.find_elements_by_css_selector('div.player')

for player in players:
    link = player.find_element_by_class_name('player-popup')
    players_info.append(link.get_attribute('href'))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could simply do:

```
listbase = ["https://rotogrinders.com/players/charlie-culberson-13456?format=json",
        "https://rotogrinders.com/players/charlie-culberson-13456?format=json"]
_list = [element.split("/", maxsplit=4)[-1] for element in listbase]
```

Comment: Similarly, you could so something like `[u.rsplit('/')[-1] for u in urls]`. As an aside, it is usually a good idea to avoid using built-ins like `list` as variable names.

Comment: uups - you're right @benvc - it was just quick'n dirty ;)